# Is this a carpenter bee?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, bees

This bee visits our balcony every day multiple times, but only for a brief time, making it hard to take a good picture:

[image]

Here's another picture, I finally got lucky so I'm adding it to the question:

[image]

It does not look like a typical honeybee. It does not make noise as bumblebees do. It also looks a lot like it's really the same creature every day. It always comes and leaves on the exact same path. The face looks a lot like carpenter bee, but I also couldn't find one like this on the internet.

This is in central Europe.